# Are there differences/limitations in asynchronous programming between C# async/await and Java's CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, c#, asynchronous, concurrency, completable-future

I'm **comparing** **C#'s** APM(asynchronous programming model), explicitly **async/await** with
**Java's CompletableFuture**.
Are there advantages in either of them or some differences to consider when choosing one of them for a problem?
Or do you just have a preferation? Let me know.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is more similar to C#'s `Task`-based TPL infrastructure, before async/await was added to the language. The difference is significant: without async/await, you work with tasks by either synchronously waiting for them to complete, or by attaching continuations: functions which are called on some thread when the task completes. Continuations lead to "callback hell", with code consisting of lots of nested chains of callbacks, making control flow complex. Things like error handling get messy as well.

Comment: async/await takes that a step further, and lets you write callback-based code as if it was normal procedural code, with the `await` statements effectively marking the boundaries between different callbacks. The compiler takes this procedural-looking code and transforms it into a suitable set of callbacks, effectively (although it does smart things to reduce cost). This means that the code is more readable and maintainable, and things like error handling can be done using normal structures such as try/catch